# How can I make a multiple button "click to reveal" work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a relatively simple JavaScript file that allows me to click one of 5 buttons and information is revealed on the screen. Currently, I have it working a single reveal but the others do not appear.

Simply put the goal would be to have it so that if I click "Selection 1" then the text "test 1" would appear, "Selection 2" and "test 2", so on and so on...

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap 4, from LayoutIt!</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Source code generated using layoutit.com">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h3>
                        1
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h3 class="text-center">
                        Choose Your Selection
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                        Selection #1
                    </button>
                    <button type="button2" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                        Selection #2
                    </button>
                    <button type="button3" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                        Selection #3
                    </button>
                    <button type="button4" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                        Selection #4
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h3>
                        2
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h3 class="text-center">
                        Choose Your Option
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p id="select1" class="select">test 1</p>
                    <p id="select2" class="select">test 2</p>
                    <p id="select3" class="select">test 3</p>
                    <p id="select4" class="select">test 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var tag = document.getElementById('select1'); var button = document.querySelector('button[type="button1"]'); button.addEventListener('click', function(){ tag.classList.toggle('selecton'); }); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var tag = document.getElementById('select2'); var button = document.querySelector('button[type="button2"]'); button.addEventListener('click', function(){ tag.classList.toggle('selecton'); }); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var tag = document.getElementById('select3'); var button = document.querySelector('button[type="button3"]'); button.addEventListener('click', function(){ tag.classList.toggle('selecton'); }); </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var tag = document.getElementById('select4'); var button = document.querySelector('button[type="button4"]'); button.addEventListener('click', function(){ tag.classList.toggle('selecton'); }); </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.container-fluid {
    width:40%;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.card {
    background-color: rgb(24, 26, 27);
    border-top-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.13);
    border-right-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.13);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.13);
    border-left-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.13);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid;
}


body {background-color: #000;}


.select {display:none;}

.selecton {display: block;}
```

Comment: You have jQuery in your file.. Why not use it?

Comment: There are so many unwanted code , why are you trying <script type="text/javascript"></script> again and again.

Comment: also - There is no `type` called `button4` it is just a button

Comment: I would add an attribut to the buttons, which contains the id of the p, and then toggle after that. then it would be `jQuery('button.addACommonClassHere').on('click', function(e){ var pToFind = jQuery(this).attr('theAttr'); jQuery('#'+pToFind).show();})` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h3>
                        1
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h3 class="text-center">
                        Choose Your Selection
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <button type="button1" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-btn='btn-1'>
                        Selection #1
                    </button>
                    <button type="button2" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"  data-btn='btn-2'>
                        Selection #2
                    </button>
                    <button type="button3" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-btn='btn-3'>
                        Selection #3
                    </button>
                    <button type="button4" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" data-btn='btn-4'>
                        Selection #4
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 card">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h3>
                        2
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h3 class="text-center">
                        Choose Your Option
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p id="select1" class="select">test 1</p>
                    <p id="select2" class="select">test 2</p>
                    <p id="select3" class="select">test 3</p>
                    <p id="select4" class="select">test 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

remove button type as "button1"
it must be only "button"

js:

```
 var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-block');
  buttons.forEach(function(button, index){
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
       if(button.dataset.btn===`btn-${index}`){
            document.getElementById(`select${index}`).classList.toggle('selecton');
       }
    });
  });
```

Comment: +1 for not changing his HTML, But I would suggest, that this should not be applied to all of bootstraps `btn` class.

Comment: actually but for this code to work my prime focus was js.

Comment: I know - But your solution targets `.btn` which would meen that this event would happen on all things styled like a button with bootstrap. - and dsince you added the `data-btn` you might as well add a class that is specific to these buttons

Comment: this should work fine now. i replaced btn with btn-block in querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(() => {
        $("button[type='button1']").on("click", () => {
            $("#select1").toggleClass("selecton");
        })
        $("button[type='button2']").on("click", () => {
            $("#select2").toggleClass("selecton");
        })
        $("button[type='button3']").on("click", () => {
            $("#select3").toggleClass("selecton");
        })
        $("button[type='button4']").on("click", () => {
            $("#select4").toggleClass("selecton");
        })
    })
</script>
```

There are many rooms for improvement with the code above. But one step at a time anyway.

Comment: For example, you use use id='button1' instead of type. You can use a loop without hard coding everything. You can use `d-none` class if you are using bootstrap. But I digress